# string is too large to make repr python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile, overflow, sandbox

I am trying to make build a project (which is cloned from Github and compiled successfully by others) using python 2.7 and I get the below failure, please tell me what extra information you need to be posted here in order to guide me in this regard,

```
    return cls.dump(cls, cls(repr(exc)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 110, in dump
    return cls.dump(cls, cls(repr(exc)))
OverflowError: string is too large to make repr
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'environment' failed
make: *** [environment] Error 1'
```

Comment: it is: https://github.com/mining/mining and i used `make build`

Comment: The make command is failing in the environment target, which tries to pip install Cython and numpy, then pip install everything in requirements_dev.txt, then calls python setup.py develop for the mining package.  I'd suggest running each of these installation commands individually to find which is failing.  If it's one of the pip installs you could add this to this question, if it's setup.py you're probably better off raising a bug on the projects github tracker.

Comment: i did so, it is failing in setup.py step

Comment: but what can cause such large string errors? i suppose some other people already compiled the project and weird to see no one has faced such thing!